# MVC4 : adding roles in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, roleprovider

I have a project called `Authorization` with `CodeFirstRoleProvider` class that inherits from default `RoleProvider`

```
public class CodeFirstRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(roleName)) return;
            using(var context = new SISContext())
            {
                var role = context.Roles.SingleOrDefault(rl => rl.RoleName == roleName);//Roles table exists in database 
                if(role == null)
                {
                    var newRole = new Role
                                      {
                                          RoleId = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                          RoleName = roleName
                                      };
                    context.Roles.Add(newRole);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

In my other project `WebPortal` I want to use above method in let's say following way

```
var _role = new CodeFirstRoleProvider();
            _role.CreateRole("Admin");
            _role.CreateRole("NonAdmin");
```

now where do I need to place this code in my `webportal`? so that these roles gets added to database for the first time when the application runs.

Suppose this program runs for first time and someone clicks the register button I want to have a dropdownlist with above roles mentioned. So, these roles need to be in database before register is clicked.

Once the roles are in database I don't need to worry for the accessing these values in future. 
One way would be manually writing the value in database but I don't want to do that, since I have this function I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What If I do something like this?

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            var _role = new CodeFirstRoleProvider();//remove after role is added to database
            _role.CreateRole("Admiin");//remove after role is added to database
            _role.CreateRole("NonAdmin");//remove after role is added to database

            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
```

and once the roles are added to database i remove those code that does role adding.

Comment: what is CodeFirstRoleProvider() ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article on seeding the SimpleMembership database](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html). Even if you are not using the SimpleRoleProvider the same principals should apply since you are using code-first.